# How to have credit card option appear without enabling Pay Later option

Tags: wordpress

We recently moved to WordPress 4.3.1 and just upgraded to Civi 4.6.10. We've been having an issue with the credit card option on our donation forms since the move to WordPress. The credit card option will not appear unless you enable the Pay Later option. Which we do not wish to show.

(FYI - we have taken the label off so as to confuse our donors less. It just says "Other" now.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're coming up against this bug: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17735.  I believe CiviCRM 4.6.11 comes out Wednesday with a fix!

Answer (score -2):

It basically related to civicrm template. If you are using civicrm custom template then check the version of custom template and installed civicrm version. Both template must have the same version. Also make credit card payment processor as default processor.